# Msys2 does not install lib-files for GTK3

Tags: c++, gtk3, msys2, msys

This might be a stupid question, but here it goes.

I am trying to install Gtk3 via MSYS2 on Windows 10, like it says on its website [GTK for Windows](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php).
Right so i followed that, and now I wanted to create my application, added the directory for include files. However there are no .lib-files to link against, just a libgtk.dll in the bin folder. Shouldn't there be lib-files in the lib folder? I really like the MSYS2 idea, but why does it have to throw every file into the same folder, can you change that somehow?

It also does not install the lib-files for the dependencies like cairo, i do not get it.

Comment: I've always downloaded directly from [download.gnome.org/sources/gtk+](https://download.gnome.org/sources/gtk+/) and just created a `c:\opt` directory and installed Gtk there for all MinGW/Msys installs. Never had any problems. I don't use `cmake` though. I have notes on the Gtk+2 install in the [gtkwrite-Readme on github](https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkwrite) at the bottom of the page. May help?

Comment: These Files are for linux, no? I would need binaries for windows *~*

Comment: There are windows binaries there. That's how I build on windows.

Comment: Ah, i didnt find it at first, but sadly i am looking for gtk3 binaries and under https://download.gnome.org/binaries/win64/gtk+/ there are only gtk2 binaries

Comment: If you installed the original Gtk+3 binaries with `pacman`, then you can use `pacman -Ql mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3`, etc.. to see where the packages are installed. I don't use Gtk+3 (other than to cuss the design choices that were made), but you simply need to make sure the `pkg-config` (`.pc`) files can be found so the right library search and include paths are set correctly at compile time. You should be able to type `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` if things are installed right and have the proper include paths returned.

Comment: oh ok, so i link the .dll.a-files, never heard of those, well thank you, using pkg-config did the trick

Comment: Yes, I use Linux only, but wanted to build the [gtkwrite](https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkwrite) on windows as well, so I had to stumble through the process a couple of years ago. Win10 is better behaved with compiling with `pkg-config` from the command line. Earlier windows gave fits unless each include path or library path was double-quoted, etc.. After you add the `..\MinGW\bin` directory to your path (in the environment variables dialog), you can actually build from the windows command prompt just fine. Good luck with your project.

Comment: What was the solution to this? I'm having the same issue.